# Prevent Scrolling in IE on Windows Phone 7

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, mobile, mobile-website

Is there any way to prevent the user from scrolling the contents of a WebBrowser control in a Windows Phone 7 application, but still allowing them to interact with the contents (click buttons, check checkboxes, etc.)

Thanks

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Talked to the IE team at Microsoft, this isn't possible.

Comment: Who did you talk to? What exactly did they say?

Comment: Please add a quote from the IE team

Comment: Sorry, it was over two years ago, it was through back channels, don't remember who, and they wouldn't have wanted to be quoted.  Rolled off the project a year ago.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, you can do the following:

- Locate the `Border` element within the `WebBrowser` that captures touch events and forwards them to thw native browser control.
- Detect scroll interactions and cancel these events.

I have created a simple utility class that performs this and blogged about it here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/

To disable scrolling do the following:

```
var browserHelper = new WebBrowserHelper(webBrowser);
browserHelper.ScrollEnabled= false;
```

Comment: Very nice.  Do you have a particular licensing for software you post (/me crosses his fingers hoping it's "free as in beer")?

Comment: Sure, you are free to use it. I should place an MS-PL license on the website somewhere at some point. A link to my blog if you use it would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use meta tags to fix the zoom (`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />`
), then you can probably use javascript to fix the scroll position - but overall I suspect this won't look very nice.

Can you tell us a bit more about what effect you are looking for? e.g. If you're trying to use scroll position to control what content is visible, then you might be better off using javascript to dynamically choose which elements are visible instead - e.g. using jquery to show/hide content.

Comment: I'm building a UI where some components can be replaced later on using HTML skinned to look like the UI.  Ultimately this will be placed statically and seamlessly on the page, but if the user drags in this area it looks really weird because of the scrolling.

Comment: Also, I've got the viewport and the javascript that returns the scrolling to the top left, but it's pretty obvious what's happening, not a good look at all.

Comment: Does this dynamic UI have to be HTML? There are a few dynamic XAML projects around - or if you can you could stand the extra download size then you could build the UI in IronRuby? (I've done this plenty in iron7.com - but this does add an extra 2MB to your app)

Comment: You could try fixing the user-scalable of the viewport and then using FIXED positioning within the HTML/CSS to make your HTML elements stay in position... but all these solutions are feeling ugly... sorry :/

Comment: I like the idea of dynamic Xaml, and if I can't find a better answer to this, that's a potential direction to go, but in the mantime the boss wants it done with html.  Also, I checked out fixed positioning, IE on Windows Phone 7 treats it like absolute